# Getting on click using getchildren()

Tags: lua, roblox

I have an area which has button numbers from 0 to 9 on roblox studio and I want to get all the children from that folder and also get the clickdetector for all of them but I dont know how. Please help thank you.

Managed to get the children but didnt manage to get the click detector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you also want to get the click detector for all of the buttons, so here you go.

```
local folder = --reference
local t = {}

for i,v in pairs (folder:GetChildren()) do
  if v:FindFirstChild("ClickDetector") then
      table.insert(t,v)
  end
end

--do whatever you want next now because you have the objects/buttons you want
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. May I ask what the the i, v and t used for? So for i, v and table.insert(t,v)? Thank you

Comment: i stands for the index of the iteration or item if you prefer, v is the value. Both of these combined forms the for loop for object iteration, you can also use for loops in "C" format i think, you can in normal lua but im not sure about luau. It goes like "for i=n, limit, increment do". T is a table which is used to store multiple items